# What are the major differences between the Roman Catholic Church and the Eastern Catholic Churches?

Tags: catholicism

Do the priests of the Eastern Catholic Churches attend seminary school before ordination?

Comment: You're asking two questions here. Please ask them one at a time.

Comment: I rolled back the edit because I believe this question is asking about the differences between the *Roman* and the [*Eastern* Catholic Churches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Catholic_Churches), not the Eastern Orthodox Churches. It's probably still too broad, and asking two different things as I wrote before.